# How to use Stored Procedure in Netsuite?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, netsuite

I'm very new to Netsuite & database administration and I was wondering if there is a way how to connect Netsuite to any database like SQL Server or MySQL so I can perform script updates?

I've looked into this - http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/DN1/ado/

Any experiences in using that?

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite sells an ODBC connection that will give you ODBC access to *read* the data. It won't allow updates.

The link you provided doesn't connect NetSuite to a SQL Server or MySQL database. It gives you an ADO.NET interface to connect to NetSuite. You'd have to write code using their interface.

We're doing our customization using SuiteScript and SuiteFlow.